# Testing a exported Constant Object

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am having some problems when trying to test my `constants.ts` file; it contains the following;

```
export const Constants = Object.freeze({
  "key":"value",
  "key2":"value",
  "key3":"value",
  "key4":"value",
})
```

Sonar tells me that I need to coverage the line: `export const Constants = Object.freeze({.`

How can I do the spec file to test it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Code coverage is not always 100%, that is a unicorn, and when not, it commonly should be. Constants are constants, they simply exists. I guess you can test them for what they are.
2. With regards to your constants file, are you sure you do not want them to be a part of your angular 'environment' file?